# Ruby on Rails - update fields based on f.select value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a dropdown box to chose the number of tickets that one wants to buy. I want to update the fields after it to reflect the value once it is clicked. Here is a snippet of my form currently:

```
    <%= form_for :transaction, :url => new_transaction_path(:event_id => @event.id), :method => 'GET' do |f| %>
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #999999">
          <td><h4>Number of Guests</h4></td>
          <td>
            <%= f.select(:quantity, (1..20))%>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #999999">
          <!-- replace (1) with the value from the f.select dropdown -->
          <td><h4><%= @original_event_price %> x (1) guest(s)</h4></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <%= f.submit 'Request to Book', class: 'button mt1 btn-request-to-book' %>
    <% end %>
```

I want to replace (1) with the value from the f.select dropdown in the last table row to the value of guests that the user chooses.

**EDIT WITH WORKING SOLUTION**

```
<%= form_for :transaction, :url => new_transaction_path(:event_id => @event.id), :method => 'GET' do |f| %>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #999999">
      <td><h4>Number of Guests</h4></td>
      <td>
        <%= f.select :quantity, (1..20), {}, { :onChange=>'mytest()', :id=>'quantitySelect' } %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #999999">
      <!-- replace (1) with the value from the f.select dropdown -->
      <td><h4><%= @original_event_price %> x (1) guest(s)</h4></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <%= f.submit 'Request to Book', class: 'button mt1 btn-request-to-book' %>
<% end %>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mytest() {
    var quantity = $('#quantitySelect').val();
    $('#quantityRow').html("<h4><%= @original_event_price %> x (" + quantity + ") guest(s)");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery:

Let's add an id: "quantitySelect" on the quantity field
Let's also add an id: "quantityRow" on the td field

```
$(function(){
  $('.quantitySelect').change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var quantity = $('.quantitySelect').val();
    $('.quantityRow').html("<h4><%= @original_event_price %> x (" + quantity + ") guest(s)");
  });
});
```

You can also add if checks to see if the quantity is > 1 and append the word guest to guests.

Comment: Hmm I tried this, and it doesn't seem to update when I click it. Can you maybe alter my code to show how you would add the id to the td and the f.select element?

Comment: Actually, I think the issue is with the jquery. I have an html.erb page being loaded by my application.html.erb via <%= yield %> so where would I put the Jquery?

Comment: You can load jquery via the gem or include it using a script tag and linking it to googles hosted jquery glad to see it worked using vanilla js though :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem** : *How to load value in other field based on drop-down selection*

**Solution**:

```
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= form.label :grade %>
  <%= form.select(:grade, options_for_select(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']), {:include_blank => 'Select Grade'}, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Grade", onchange: "loadRemarksBasedOnGrade()") %>
</div>

<div class="field form-group">
  <%= form.label :remarks %>
  <%= form.text_field :remarks, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Remarks", readonly: true %>
</div>
```

**JavaScript** :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadRemarksBasedOnGrade() {
    var grades = [];
    grades['A'] = "Excellent";
    grades['B'] = "Very Good";
    grades['C'] = "Good";
    grades['D'] = "Average";
    grades['E'] = "Below average";
    grades['F'] = "Failed";

    let grade = document.getElementById("student_grade");
    if(grades[grade.value] !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("student_remarks").value = grades[grade.value];
    } else {
      document.getElementById("student_remarks").value = "";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Note: So onchnage event loadRemarksBasedOnGrade update value based on id.